# How to get the attribute value of an html tag using simpleHTMLDom?

Tags: simple-html-dom

I want to get the content of an attribute for example : `<a href="#" title="theTitle" class="foo"></a>` How to parse and get `"theTitle"` ?

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=foo]') as $ClassContent)
```

This gives the content of the `<div>` i know but any way to get `theTitle` please ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".foo").attr("title");
```

Comment: Any way to perform it using php ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, plaintext gives the text between tags

For : `<a href='#' class="foo" title='TheTitleToGet'></a>` to get `title` content :

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=foo]') as $getTitle){
        $title = array();
        $title [] = $getTitle->title;
}
```

This will get all titles written inside attribute `title`. same if you want `src` for `<img src="someSRC">` only do `img[] = $getImgSRC->src`

Thank you.